# How to implement a navigation controller in a subclass?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Can anyone tell me about how to implement a navigation controller in a UIView subclass?
I am creating four sub-classes, and I do not want the navigation control in first class, but I need to place it in the second, third and fourth subclass. How can I do that?

Can anybody help me? How do I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If you dnt want navigation control in first class then you can hide the navigationBar by 
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES; and this has to be in the next class
self.navController.navigationBarHidden = NO;

Comment: duble click the xib file of mainWindow.xib and add a navigation controller to the window then double click the navigation controller and a view will come click on the view and in the inspector select the xib file and select the class in the last tab

Answer (score 0):

When you call 2nd, 3rd and 4th view from 1st one (which does not have navigation bar) then call it as below:

```
RootViewController * rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

Comment: when i call this method, the navigationbar is shown and its not placed correctly. Exactly navigation bar placed from 20pixels from top of simulator. how to solve this.

Comment: so i guess the status bar is not shown above that, because status bar is having 20pixel height. See in IB that you have kept statusbar enabled. or setFrame for navigationbar.